# How to disable mat-calendar control?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to disable the `mat-calendar` control? (not specific days, but the control it self).

```
  <mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar)

I try to add `[disabled]="true"` but I got an error: `Can't bind to 'disable' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-calendar'`.

I search at [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) but can't find any relevant information about it.

This is it possible?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-disabled

Comment: @R.Richards your example say to add `disabled`. but `disabled` is not for `mat-calendar`. try yourself instead to do downvote.

Comment: see the stackbliz example and you will find why I ask this question. and your question link is not the for same control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable it, simply dont update the value of the `selectedDate` in your `onSelect` event.

e.g. if you want to allow users to only set the value, once, simply add another flag that you trigger on the first change:

```
  ...component...
  disabled = false;

  onSelect(event) {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedDate = event;
    this.disabled = true;
  }
```

you can remove the event completely and set the value in the component, and then the calendar will be always disabled

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar-nxkwb5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for first example